# Connecting to server via NFS with different (external) IP addresses

Tags: networking, ftp, mount, nfs

Is it possible to connect to my FTP server via the NFS protocol (my server is running Linux) from another computer outside my internal network?

I have set it up in the past to use my LAN IP 10.0.0.X, but how would it work via external IP if your nfs-server needs to have an IP address bound? If at all possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is possible, although not necessarily advisable due to the added security risks.

Your server would need to be bound to an externally reachable IP address, or you could go through the hoops required to map all the appropriate ports from your router to the server.

A better way to do it might be to set up a VPN to your system which adds a layer of protection via encrypting the data and requiring additional authentication - and this will also get through your firewall.  The big if though is if you can get your router to support VPN access.  Most home routers don't do this off the shelf, but I know its possible to do with OpenWRT and I am pretty sure DD-WRT will allow this also.

Before getting all complex though, have you considered if you actually need NFS.  If its going to be linux -> linux, have you considered the much simpler route of sshfs (ie mounting the filesystem over SSH) - this is a lot simpler and more secure - particularly as you only have 1 port to worry about and the security is baked in to the protocol.